# Check if all elements have been hovered over

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

I am trying to trigger an animation once all elements have completed 'mouseleave'.

so here is a snippet (I have this repeated for the other elements named "box1, box3" as well)

```
$("#box4").mouseleave(function () {

    $(".contentBox4").hide("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    }, 100);
    $("#box4.gridBox.grid-darker").fadeTo(500, 0);

    $(this).unbind("mouseenter").unbind("mouseleave");

});

var boxes = ('#box1, #box3, #box4');
var hasBeenHovered = false;

$(boxes).mouseleave(function () {
    hasBeenHovered = true;

    if (hasBeenHovered) {
        $(".introTitle").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

So right now, when mouse leaves each of the elements, it performs the animation, rather than.. when it leaves ALL of the said elements.

So if anyone can provide any insight, much thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the mouse leaves a box, check if all boxes has been hovered by using `data()` to set a flag once a box is hovered etc :

```
var boxes = $('#box1, #box3, #box4');

boxes.one('mouseleave', function() {
    var allHovered = true;
    $(this).data('hovered', true);

    boxes.each(function(i, box) {
        if ( $(box).data('hovered') != true ) allHovered = false;
    });

    if (allHovered)
       $(".introTitle").fadeIn();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JP3hM/)

Answer (score 2):

I would simply store the ids of the yet hovered elements :

```
(function(){
    var boxes = $('#box1, #box3, #box4'); 
    var yetHoveredElements = {}, nbToHover = boxes.length;
    boxes.mouseleave(function(){
           if (yetHoveredElements[this.id]) return;
           yetHoveredElements[this.id] = true;
           if (--nbToHover==0) {
              $(".introTitle").fadeIn(); 
           }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Adeneo's answer was a little easier to understand, but your answer is clever and taught me some new tricks. Thanks. +1

Comment: Thank you very much.  Finally was able to check out this version..and I agree with gibberish.  Another way to look at it. Thanks dystroy